# How to find duplicate index - value pairs with same values in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently trying to write a JS function that can identify and return indexes in JSON object which have same values.

For example:

```
var objSample = {
    a : 'a',
    b : 'b',
    c : 'a',
    d : 'd',
    e : 'a'
};
```

So, in the above example, the value *'a'* is only valid for 1st index and invalid at *c* and *e* indexes. How do I find all the indexes which are duplicate in the object?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: btw, objects have keys or properties. indices apply only for arrays.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help

Comment: Objects are logically unordered collections (even if modern JS does define a property iteration order).  So who's to say that properties `c` and `e` are duplicates of property `a` and not that `a` and `e` are duplicates of `c` or some such?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var objSample = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'a',
  d: 'd',
  e: 'a'
};

keys = Object.keys(objSample).filter(key => objSample[key] === key)

console.log(keys)
```

Here's what the code actually does:

First, it gets the keys to the array. These are what the things before the colon marks are.

After that, it checks if the key is equal to the element the key refers to in the array. If so, it keeps the key. If not, it removes it. This is done by the filter statement.

In the end, this results in an array with all the elements with 'duplicates'.

Comment: Elegant one-liner ️ As you probably noticed, the asker has issues with JSON-terminology (`index` instead of _key_ for object's properties). It will certainly help, if you could __explain your code__: e.g. what `Object.keys` does, how a filter works, what the predicate tests. Make your answer stand-out ️

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on the object and maintain the iterated values in an array. In every iteration, check whether you have that value in the memorized array or not. If not push it to the array else its duplicate.
Here is a sample code

```
var objSample = {
  a : 'a',
  b : 'b',
  c : 'a',
  d : 'd',
  e : 'a'
};

var values = [];

for( key in objSample) {
  if(values.indexOf(objSample[key]) > -1){
    console.log(`${objSample[key]} is duplicate for ${key} index`);
  } else {
    values.push(objSample[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The code and explanation is well-adapted to a JavaScript beginner: simple language-constructs at entry-level ⭐️

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the keys and get the ones with duplicate values.

```js
const
    data = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'a', d: 'd', e: 'a' },
    sameValues = Object
        .keys(data)
        .filter((seen => k => seen[data[k]] || !(seen[data[k]] = true))({}));

console.log(sameValues);
```